# Windows 2008: can't access network shares, even with \\localhost, 0x80070035 or 0x80070043 errors

Tags: networking, network-share

This was working fine but after an unexpected reboot.

In Explorer, on the Windows 2008 server itself, I can see the shared folders when I do this: \\localhost (or \\servername or \\192.168.1.7) But when I try to click on any of the folders (like \\localhost\folder1), I get 0x80070035 or 0x80070043 "The network path was not found".

What's wrong here?

Comment: 0x80070035 is "The network path was not found".
0x80070043 is "The network name could not be found".
You're not picking up anything funny in the event logs?

Comment: Are ports 445 and 139 listening?

Comment: Could this be related to your other questions?...

Comment: Have you installed SP 2 on this Server?

Comment: Yes, SP2 is installed. No firewall, AV.  Nothing suspicious in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of reboots fixed the problem.  I still don't know what went wrong.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

My issue was fixed by opening an administrative cmd session and issuing the netsh winsock reset and then restarting the server.